# Adding Pagination to AngularJS Table

Tags: angularjs, pagination

So I am getting some dynamic data and am able to get it to display, but I now want to add some pagination, I have seen that there are modules that can do this but with my limited experience with Angular I haven't been able to get one to work. Below is my table in my HTML, and basically in my Javascript I am running a REST POST call that returns the data and display it in the table below, however if I wanted to use pagination instead of displaying the whole table, how would I do so, I'm not trying to do anything fancy but I have tried some Jquery plugins in addition to the angularjs modules have not figured it out, I thought there may be a way to do this with a simple table like shown below, if anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th><b>ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Score</b></th>
    <th><b>Number</b></th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="data in restCtrl.results">
    <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.score }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.number }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have use `ng-repeat="data in restCtrl.results | filter : paginate"` with $resource:

http://plnkr.co/edit/79yrgwiwvan3bAG5SnKx?p=preview

Comment: So other than getting the pagination options to display, I haven't gotten it to work, I replaced my ng-repeat with what you put above, I put the <pagination></pagination> under my table, and then i added the function to my javascript file but none of the buttons work.

Comment: Do not forgot to load angular-resource.js

Comment: this has a flaw which only orders the data on the current page if if it's desc